# How do I fetch data from next page from youtube playlist in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have tried with pageToken, but the problem is when first 50 elements are added into videos list, after that next 50 are not adding.After showing first 50 data and when it should get next 50, it is showing the error:
        RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..28, inclusive: 50
I will be very grateful if I get the solution, Thanks in advance.

```
class _PlaylistPageState extends State<PlaylistPage> {
  bool isMore = false;
  Map data = new Map();
  List<dynamic> videos = new List();

getData() async {
    String baseUrl =
        "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=${widget.plist}" +
            "&maxResults=50&key=" +
            "AIzaSyCrrzqrXMfI8xpD0a5wdU1xDcc7QTUjLSA";
    String nextPageUrl =
        "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=${widget.plist}" +
            "&maxResults=50&pageToken=CDIQAA&key=" +
            "AIzaSyCrrzqrXMfI8xpD0a5wdU1xDcc7QTUjLSA";

    var baseResponse;
    var nextPageResponse;
    if(!isMore){
      baseResponse = await http.get(baseUrl);
    } else {
      nextPageResponse = await http.get(nextPageUrl);
    }


      setState(() {
        if(!isMore){
          videos.add(json.decode(baseResponse.body)["items"]);
        } else {
          videos.add(json.decode(nextPageResponse.body)["items"]);
        }
      });
  }

  fetchTen(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      getData();
    }
  }

 ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchTen();
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
          _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        if(videos.length == 50){
          setState(() {
            isMore = true;
          });
        }
        //print(videos.length);
        fetchTen();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
          child:ListView.builder(
              controller: _scrollController,
              itemCount: videos == null ? 0 : videos.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Material(
                    elevation: 8.0,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          height: 200,
                          width: 300,
                          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                              image: new DecorationImage(
                                image: new NetworkImage(videos[index][index]["snippet"]
                                ["thumbnails"]["high"]["url"]),
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
                          ),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: new Center(child: Text(videos[index][index]["snippet"]["title"], textAlign: TextAlign.center,),),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              })
    );
  }
```

I expected to have all the video list in the playlist,  But I am getting only first 50 perfectly. So, how to get all videos from youtube playlist ?

Answer (score 0):

You can put a while loop which checks if nextPageToken is null or not and if it isn't you continue to fetch it and save in a temporary list. After it has been done you can just save it in your original list.

```
while (pageToken != null) {
  final response = await DataFetcher(
      playlistId: playlistId,
      pageToken: pageToken)
      .FetchVideoFromPlaylist();
  final extracted_data = json.decode(response) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  pageToken = extracted_data['nextPageToken'];
  List<dynamic> data = extracted_data['items'];
  data.forEach((item) {
    title = item['snippet']['title'];
    thumbnail_url = item['snippet']['thumbnails']['high']['url'];
    videoid = item['contentDetails']['videoId'];
    print(title);
    videoDet.add(
        new VideoDetails(
            videoId: videoid,
            videoUrl: null,
            video_thumbnail: thumbnail_url,
            video_title: title)
    );
  });

  if (id == 1)
    cdVideoData = videoDet;}
```

**In this DataFetcher is a function which is used to fetch videos from youtube. And videodet is a temporary list used to store videos until it finishes adding all**